# ADO: Opening a recordset to add new record

Tags: ado, recordset

In this example the only reason I am opening a recordset is to allow me to INSERT a record into the table using ADO .addNew method.

Are there memory implications that would make it better to open a recordset with just one record rather than opening a table that might possibly have thousands of rows?

Code example:

```
//Create a recordset object
var rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");

// Select just the top record to increase efficiency ?????  
var mySource = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyThousandRecordTable";

// OR...

// The whole table
var mySource = "MyThousandRecordTable";

rs.Open(mySource, adoConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic);

rs.AddNew

//loop fields dynamically and assign values
for (var key in model){
    val = [some code that gets a value]
    rs.Fields(key) = val+"";
}

rs.Update    
//clean up
rs.Close();
rs = null;
```

Does opening just the top row save resources and affect efficiency?

I guess the basic question I am asking here is - does using the tablename instead of a SELECT query load the entire table into memory?

Comment: The approach I am using - to simply hand the name of the table to rs.Open in order to access the rs.AddNew method can be found in lots of examples I have found. But does it make sense to open up the entire table - possibly 10's of thousands of records? Just need to add some records via ADO rs.AddNew. The purpose of creating a RS is load the "model" found in the table right? Can be done with one record. TOP 1.